# Programming a GUI with Eclipse Plugin Jigloo

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, console

Testing a GUI with the Run Button, there is an Error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jgoodies.looks.plastic.Plastic3DLookAndFeel
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.loadSystemClass(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(Unknown Source)
at com.fbtm.seminar.Kpp.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:35)
at com.fbtm.seminar.Kpp.JFrame$1.run(JFrame.java:55)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The GUI runs perfect with these error but how can I solve these problem(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you have used a look and feel (Plastic3DLookAndFeel) that you don't have in your classpath, try adding the relative jar to the classpath .

Take a look [here](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/com.jgoodies.looks.plastic.Plastic3DLookAndFeel) .